# Kivy - Label not updating using StringProperty

Tags: bluetooth, kivy, label

I am a newbie in python programming so I will be glad for any help about the problem that I am facing now.

I wrote code where I simply sending text "Fire" to a bluetooth module by pressing the button, and also I want to receive a text from bluetooth and put it in text label. Problem is that I definitely receive the text I can see it on debug print but Kivy label is not updating.

Here is my code:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import threading
import time

# Same as before, with a kivy-based UI

'''
Bluetooth/Pyjnius example
=========================
This was used to send some bytes to an arduino via bluetooth.
The app must have BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permissions (well, i didn't
tested without BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, maybe it works.)
Connect your device to your phone, via the bluetooth menu. After the
pairing is done, you'll be able to use it in the app.
'''

from jnius import autoclass


BluetoothAdapter = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter')
BluetoothDevice = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice')
BluetoothSocket = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket')
UUID = autoclass('java.util.UUID')

exit_flag = 0

def print_time(threadName, delay, counter):
    while counter:
        #if exitFlag:
        #    threadName.exit()
        time.sleep(delay)
        print ("%s: %s" % (threadName, time.ctime(time.time())))
        counter -= 1

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter, inputStream):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.inputStream = inputStream
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
        print("Starting " + self.name)
        counter = 5
        mensaje = ""
        while counter:
            if (self.inputStream.available()):
                input_chr = chr(self.inputStream.read())
                mensaje = mensaje + input_chr
                if (input_chr == '\n'):
                    print(mensaje)# debug recieved text output 
                    Mylbl.txt_string = mensaje
                    mensaje = ""
            #counter -= 1
        print_time(self.name, self.counter, 5)
        print("Exiting " + self.name)



def get_socket_stream(name):
    paired_devices = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices().toArray()
    print("========================")
    print([ x.getName() for x in paired_devices ])
    print(paired_devices)
    socket = None
    for device in paired_devices:
        print(device.getName())
        if device.getName() == name:
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"))
            recv_stream = socket.getInputStream()
            send_stream = socket.getOutputStream()
            break
    socket.connect()
    return recv_stream, send_stream

Builder.load_string("""
<MyLbl>:
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            id: lbl1
            text: str(root.txt_string)
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.7}
            font_size: 200
        Button:
            id: btn1
            text: "Fire"
            font_size: 50
            size_hint: 0.6,0.3
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.3}
            background_color: (1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
            on_press: app.send(self.text)
""")
class Mylbl(FloatLayout):
    txt_string = StringProperty('###')


class Bluetooth(App):
    def build(self):
        #self.recv_stream, self.send_stream = get_socket_stream('linvor')
        self.recv_stream, self.send_stream = get_socket_stream('HC-06')
        self.input_thread = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1, self.recv_stream)
        self.input_thread.start()
        return Mylbl()

    def send(self, cmd):
        #self.send_stream.write('{}\n'.format(cmd))
        self.send_stream.write("Fire\n".encode())
        print(cmd)
        print(self.send_stream)
        Mylbl.txt_string = "***"
        self.send_stream.flush()


#Bluetooth().run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Bluetooth().run()
```

Please give me advice what I should fix to make it work.

I checked everything with debug print in code but I haven't found the answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from this line:

```py
    Mylbl.txt_string = "***"
```

`Mylbl` is a class, not a widget instance. An `App` instance can access the root of the widget tree with its `root` attribute, so replacing this line with

```py
    self.root.txt_string = "***"
```

ought to fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Tell me also how to fix this line "Mylbl.txt_string = mensaje" it also  can't update the label text , should i fix it in same way?

Comment: For any class method whose first argument is `self`, `self` refers to the instance of the class. In this case, the line `Mylbl.txt_string = mensaje` occurs in a method from the class  `myThread`, so  `self.root.txt_string = mensaje` won't give us the desired result. Instead, you should do `App.get_running_app().root.txt_string = mensaje`.